# Google SignIn для разных пакетов одного приложения

Tags: android, google-account

Проблема в следующем. Одно приложение в зависимости от версии билда может иметь разные виды пакетов. 1 com.app.v 2. ru.app.c. Разделение настроено через градл через productFlavors и поле applicationId. Я добавил регистрацию через Google SignIn, Для первого варианта наименования пакетов всё хорошо, регистрация проходит, а вот когда собираю под второй вариант, то регистрация не проходит, в активити резалт возвращается флаг RESULT_CANCELED и никакой информации об аккаунте.
Клеинт айди добавлял в запрос. В самом кабинете настроены проекты для обоих пакетов. Проекты в кабинете разные.

Comment: Используйте для получения имени пакета BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда на проекте больше одного варианта сборки с изменением applicationId,при генерации sha1 генерится несколько вариантов этого ключа, вам необходимо искать ключ именно той сборки которая указана в Gradle и прописать его в аккаунте. На первый взгляд они примерно одиннаковые.